# how to jest test an async action with axios in react?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have an action-generator register.js:

```
import { REGISTER_SUCCESS, REGISTER_FAIL } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";

export const register = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  const { name, email, password } = formData;
  const configRegister = {
    method: "post",
    url: "/api/users",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    data: { name, email, password },
  };
  try {
    const res = await axios(configRegister);
    const token = res.data.token;
    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: {
        token,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_FAIL,
      payload: {
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        loading: true,
      },
    });
  }
};
```

the endpoint `/api/users` returns `{token:'a_token_string'}` on being successful.

**How should i test this action-generator using jest ?**

I tried doing this, register.test.js :-

```
import {
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
} from "./types";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
import axios from "axios";

jest.mock("axios");
    
/** mock-store */
const createMockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
const defaultState = [];
const store = createMockStore(defaultState);
/** reset mock */
afterEach(() => jest.resetAllMocks());

test("should register a  user ", async () => {
  axios.post.mockImplementation(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      status: 200,
      body: {
        token: "testToken",
      },
    });
  });
  const res = await axios.post("/api/users");
  console.log(res.body);
  const testUser = {
    name: "testName",
    email: "test@email.com",
    password: "testPassword",
  };
  await store.dispatch(register(testUser)).then(() => {
    expect(store.getActions()[0]).toEqual({
      type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: {
        token: "testToken",
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close to get it done. The thing is you're mocking `axios.post` while your implementation is using directly from `axios` object. As long as you mock `axios` object then it would work as it should. Here is proposed changes, please check inline comments for things you should also change:

```js
test("should register a user ", async () => {
  // Mock `axios` object directly
  axios.mockImplementation(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      status: 200,
      // should also change from `body` to `data` as well
      data: {
        token: "testToken",
      },
    });
  });
  
  // it will no longer work since the mock is changed
  // const res = await axios.post("/api/users");
  // console.log(res.body);

  const testUser = {
    name: "testName",
    email: "test@email.com",
    password: "testPassword",
  };
  await store.dispatch(register(testUser)).then(() => {
    expect(store.getActions()[0]).toEqual({
      type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: {
        token: "testToken",
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked. i am kind of new to this , can you please show me how to write test for REGISTER_FAIL case.

Comment: You just need to change your mock in in the failure case as following: `axios.mockRejectedValue({ status: 500 /* whatever you want since you just log it though */ })`

Comment: i had to show you my code. so i made a new question. can you please look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65857289/how-to-jest-test-an-async-action-with-axios-in-react-part-2